# Encoding a JSON web token

Tags: jwt

I am sending some user data to the client which is secret user data.

Is it a good practise encoding a **JSON web token** and send it to the client?

Answer (score 0):

"Encoding" is not "encrypting" - you should really encrypt anything that might be sensitive.

The `zip` format supports password protected encryption and is reasonably safe for most day-to-day uses. Just make sure you send the zip file & the password separately :)